# CSS spacing after each item in list with responsive web design

Tags: css, mobile, bulletedlist

I am generating a bulleted list on a web site (by using a jquery auto-complete function) and 
am using responsive web design in the web site.

I want a space after each list item.   I have added the following CSS to do so:

```
 li
 {
    margin-bottom:20px;       
 }
```

However, when there is word wrap on a list item (say on mobile device), the total line spacing does not change.

I don't get proper spacing between the bottom of the word wrapped item and the next item.

The display looks like this:

[image]

How can I get the spacing to look like this:

[image]

I tried putting up a jsfiddle, but can't get the css for the jquery autocomplete (that works in my app) to work, let alone the css for the line spacing I added.

Here it is anyway, fyi:

http://jsfiddle.net/2hwn4/

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS related to the problem.  Better yet provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Lowkase I will put a simplified version of this on jsfiddle when I have time

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with CSS specificity? http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

If your code is like the fiddle you posted, inspecting an `li` item in the autocomplete will show you that the following attributes are being applied (coming from the jquery ui css file):

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    zoom: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This rule is more specific than your

```
li
 {
    margin-bottom:20px;       
 }
```

So, the actual bottom margin being applied is 0.
To fix this, you can do a `margin-bottom: 20px !important;` (*not recommended), or use the same selector to overwrite the jquery ui (assuming your CSS is loaded after jquery ui css) like this:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried putting the css for the autocomplete in the same aspx page as the autocomplete control instead of in an external page so as to override the jquery css. And what you suggested did not help.